# .obj files not sending xhr post

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, form-data, jqxhr

I have a jquery code where I send files with xhr post, this code works fine for other files but for files with ".obj" extension it doesn't send any value in post (it doesn't send test data independent of the file either)

*When I print the file value to the console, I can see that it is written correctly*

Code;

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("file", file);
form.append("test", "test");

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "desk.php", true);
xhr.onload = function ()
{
    if (xhr.status == 200)
    {
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(response);
    }

};
xhr.send(form);
```

Comment: "*it doesn't send any value in post*" - how do you know? Where are you printing the values? Did you look in the network panel of your browser devtools to validate whether the file was sent?

Comment: Sounds more likely that an overcautious WAF, antivirus or PHP configuration doesn't accept `.obj` files

Comment: When I looked at payload I saw that it was sent, but in php side I can't receive this sent post

Comment: Then the JS code seems to work and is irrelevant for the problem. Post the PHP code instead, as well as your PHP configuration, and a description of your deployment with all the middlewares between the browser and the PHP code.